# How can I change the default browser on Xiaomi Mi Max phones?

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications, xiaomi

How can I setup in my phone (Android 7 mimax 2) in way that every link or pop-up will be opened by chrome.
In the past I was able to choose how to open. Now the called "browser" browser only does it

Comment: @Rahul Hôpital thanks so much You can make it an answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MIUI 9**

Go to Settings-> Installed Apps. On top you have three dots, tap on that three dots will pop up a menu, select `Default app`. Under browser part, set Chrome as default. After this operation, every link you open will be loaded in Chrome browser.

**MIUI 8**

Go to installed apps as described above. While when you are in Installed apps, you can see an icon written with Defaults. Tap on it, and set required.

Note: MIUI is the user interface of Xiaomi devices. MIUI 9 is the latest now.

Comment: In the mi max 3 with android version 9 PKQ1.181007.001 there is not "installed apps on the setting"

Comment: Please mention your current Miui version